# O SO não faz busca dentro do código?

Tags: suporte

Recentemente fiz uma pergunta, [Erro ao criar tabela: Invalid default value for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195268/erro-ao-criar-tabela-invalid-default-value-for), no qual pesquisei antes de fazer-la, que é o que todo mundo deveria fazer aqui.

Apartemente não apareceu nada quando coloquei na busca desta forma: ["Invalid default value for"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Invalid%20default%20value%20for%22), e entre aspas mesmo. Logo depois o @rray comentou com uma possível solução em outra pergunta: [Erro com valor padrão para campo datetime no MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136738/erro-com-valor-padr%C3%A3o-para-campo-datetime-no-mysql) , que no caso possui o mesmo valor de busca, porém agora só aparece minha pergunta.

O que pode estar acontecendo? O SO não faz busca dentro do código?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao adicionar aspas duplas no termo da busca, ela é feita para combinar o termo exato. Porém isso se aplica somente ao texto da pergunta e não em trechos de códigos. O link da pergunta sugeriada tem a mensagem de erro como código.

Para pesquisar código fonte, adicione `code: "termo exato"`. No caso do exemplo

```
code:"Invalid default value for"
```

Vai retorna a questão apontanda como link.

**Referência:**

[Search incorrectly returns no results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313535/1342547)

Comment: Poderia ter algo como `cotains:snippet`, `contains:code`, `contains:link` e `contains:image`, com isto a busca ficaria excelente para nós que editamos muitas perguntas e respostas com problemas =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o `contains:code` já tem é o `hascode:yes`. Não tenho certeza talvez funcione indiretamente para o snippet.

Comment: Isto é massa :D