# Sugestões para fazer buscas por postagens especificas

Tags: novo-recurso, busca

O [@rray citou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5913/3635) um exemplo que eu nunca havia notado no buscador, isto `code:"trecho de código"` e isto `hascode:yes`, achei muito útil mesmo, no entanto gostaria de sugerir os seguintes:

- `cotains:snippet` busca postagens com stack snippet/trecho
- `-contains:snippet` busca postagens que **não** contenham stack snippet
- `contains:link` busca postagens que contenham links
- `-contains:link` busca postagens que **não** contenham links
- `contains:image` busca postagens que contenham imagens
- `-contains:image` busca postagens que **não** contenham imagens

O motivo disto é que nós usuários que mais colaboramos com edições encontramos muitas postagens com problemas, principalmente do mal uso do stacksnippet:

- [Add option to search posts with 'Stack Snippets'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274626/198279)

Tem sido um trabalho de formiguinha e muitas vezes é frustante, creio que com um buscador adequando poderemos colaborar muito mais.

Com isto eu poderia buscar postagens que são sobre PHP mas por algum motivo estão provavelmente usando Stack Snippets sem necessidade, por exemplo:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+contains:snippet

Ou procurar perguntas sobre JavaScript que não contenham Stack Snippet, mas poderiam conter:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+-contains:snippet (note o hífen a frente de `contains` ele significa negação)

Assim poderíamos editar várias postagens que contenham problemas e colaborar melhor com a comunidade.